# Is there a good way to get a list of an Azure Function App's functions and their configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, command-line-interface, azure-app-service-plans

We have an Azure Function App that we want to move to a different Resource Group and Application Service Plan. The Resource Group part is easy - the UI allows us to move it. However, there does not appear to be any way to move the Application Service Plan.

Therefore, it seems the only solution is to "clone" the existing app into a new one. However, according to the docs, cloning is not supported for Function Apps.

So what I am trying to do through the `az` UI is:

1. Create a new Function App.
2. Copy the configuration from the existing app (using `az functionapp config appsettings list`) into a file.
3. Edit the file to get rid of the entries that are automatically generated when you create a new app.
4. Update the configuration of the new app with the file from #3 above.
5. Deploy the application.

The problem is that our existing app has a lot of functions, and each of those has function keys, etc. That function config data is not copied as part of the config steps above.

I have been looking at the `az` documentation, and I can see no way of extracting these function configs from the existing app, and adding them to the new app.

Is there an automated/CLI way to accomplish this? Or do I have to use the UI and do this by hand?

Comment: I understand that you want to extract the function keys of existing function app and that f-keys you want to add for the new function app using Azure CLI Cmdlets. - Is that your requirement?

Comment: Yes, I would like to be able to transfer all the individual function configs to the new app via scripting.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is to update the existing function app configuration values to the new function app i.e.,

**Using CLI Command with manually add the values to it**:

Retrieve the existing Function App Configuration using the below command:

```
az functionapp config appsettings list --name KrishFuncApp1205 --resource-group Functestrg
```

[image]

Updating the above configuration to the new function app using the below command:

```
APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY="<InstrumentationValue>"
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING="<IngestionEndpoint>"
AzureWebJobsStorage="<ConnStringValue>"
az functionapp config appsettings set --name KrishFuncApp120502 --resource-group Functestrg --settings "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY=$APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING=$APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING" "AzureWebJobsStorage=$AzureWebJobsStorage"
```

Here **`KrishFuncApp120502`** is the new Function App that I have updated its configuration with the old function App (**`KrishFuncApp1205`**) config values.

**Result**:

[image]

---

To extract the Authorization Keys for individual functions in function app, use the below command:

```
az functionapp function keys list --function-name ProdHttpTrigger --name KrishFuncApp1205 --resource-group Functestrg
```

Set/Add that same key to the new function app individual function:

```
az functionapp function keys set -g Functestrg -n KrishFuncApp120502 --function-name ProdHttpTriggerF2 --key-name pfkey --key-value prod2408
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had actually already done what you listed.

The missing step is getting a list of the functions to update with the `az functionapp function keys set` command. It looks like you are manually entering the function name for your commands. I wanted to iterate through a list of the function names that currently exist, and was hoping I could get them from a CLI command. Otherwise I'm going to have to hard-code a couple dozen names.

Comment: Hello @Westy, you want this functionality using CLI only or Azure PowerShell cmdlets also fine?

Comment: We do not have listing functions in Azure CLI but you can make [rest api calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-functions) using [Azure CLI](https://www.codeisahighway.com/native-azure-rest-api-calls-now-available-in-azure-cli-2-0-67/#:~:text=From%20the%20Azure%20CLI%20help%20you%27ll%20get%20the,a%20custom%20request.%20This%20command%20is%20in%20preview.).

Comment: Thanks again. Azure PowerShell would work too. I'll look at the REST API calls.